# Recursively disabling all children of an element

Tags: jquery

This might be a yes/no type of question.

I'm trying to disable absolutely all children of an element in jquery.

Does calling

```
$('#id_of_an_element').children().do(function(){
    do_something;
});
```

recursively call all children of an element, or does it just `do_something` to all the direct descendants of `an_element`?

Help is appreciated,

Josh

Comment: What are you hoping to do? You may not need to affect each individual descendant.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .children()
>   method allows us to search through the
>   **immediate children of these elements**
>   in the DOM tree and construct a new
>   jQuery object from the matching
>   elements. The .find() and .children()
>   methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level
>   down the DOM tree. Note also that like
>   most jQuery methods, .children() does
>   not return text nodes; to get all
>   children including text and comment
>   nodes, use .contents().

http://api.jquery.com/children/

You can do this if you want to act on all descendants at any level of nesting:

```
$('#id_of_an_element').find('*').attr('disabled', true);
```

or using the descendant selector:

```
$('#id_of_an_element *').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This may need to be adjusted slightly for _properties_, such as `disabled`, which are differentiated from _attributes_ in newer versions of jQuery.  "As of jQuery 1.6, the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes."

Comment: is there a way to do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 8):

Since you want to affect *all* descendants, just do this:

```
$('#id_of_an_element *').each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

But I'd be curious to know what exactly you're doing.

The `disabled` property is meaningless for many element types. It could be that whatever you're doing will benefit from the inheritance of CSS.

Or if you actually want the `disabled` property, then you might as well just target `form` elements.

```
$('#id_of_an_element :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: +1 good point about the `:input` selector. Definitely makes more sense than looping over all descendants.

Comment: @karim79: Thanks. Hard to say which is best, but I'd bet that the proper solution to whatever OP is doing won't involve `*`. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
function disableChildren(obj) {
    obj.children().each(function(i, val) {
         disable(val);
         disableChildren(val);
    });
}

disableChildren($("#id"));
```

See [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/Each/) There doesn't appear to be a `.do` method.

You'll have to implement `disable` as a function to do what every you want when you say "disable"